# Discord.js (v12) Giveaway Command --> Error: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Im trying to code my own discord bot and now i wanna make a giveaway command...
I researched for an example code and found this. I tested it and it's not working...

```
const ms = require('ms');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const consolewords = chalk.keyword('white');
const consoleerrcmds = chalk.keyword('yellow');

module.exports = {
    name: 'gcreate',
    description: 'Start a giveaway',
    cooldown: 5,
    args: true,
    guildOnly: true,
    usage: '|Channel| [Duration] (Winner) {Prize}',
    permission: 'Operator',
    id: 115,
    execute: async (client, message, args) => {

        if (message.member.hasPermission(['SEND_TTS_MESSAGES'])) {

            const giveawayChannel = message.mentions.channels.first();
            if(!giveawayChannel) {
                return message.channel.send(':x: You have to mention a valid channel!');
            }

            const giveawayDuration = args[1];
            if(!giveawayDuration || isNaN(ms(giveawayDuration))) {
                return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid duration!');
            }
            const giveawayNumberWinners = args[2];
            if(isNaN(giveawayNumberWinners) || (parseInt(giveawayNumberWinners) <= 0)) {
                return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid number of winners!');
            }

            const giveawayPrize = args.slice(3).join(' ');
            if(!giveawayPrize) {
                return message.channel.send(':x: You have to specify a valid prize!');
            }

            client.giveawaysManager.start(giveawayChannel, {
                time: ms(giveawayDuration),
                prize: giveawayPrize,
                winnerCount: giveawayNumberWinners,
                hostedBy: client.config.hostedBy ? message.author : null,
                messages: {
                    giveaway: (client.config.everyoneMention ? '@everyone\n\n' : '') + ' **GIVEAWAY** ',
                    giveawayEnded: (client.config.everyoneMention ? '@everyone\n\n' : '') + ' **GIVEAWAY ENDED** ',
                    timeRemaining: 'Time remaining: **{duration}**!',
                    inviteToParticipate: 'React with  to participate!',
                    winMessage: 'Congratulations, {winners}! You won **{prize}**!',
                    embedFooter: 'Giveaways',
                    noWinner: 'Giveaway cancelled, no valid participations.',
                    hostedBy: 'Hosted by: {user}',
                    winners: 'winner(s)',
                    endedAt: 'Ended at',
                    units: {
                        seconds: 'seconds',
                        minutes: 'minutes',
                        hours: 'hours',
                        days: 'days',
                        pluralS: false,
                    },
                },
            });

            message.channel.send(`Giveaway started in ${giveawayChannel}!`);
        }
        if (!message.member.hasPermission(['SEND_TTS_MESSAGES'])) {
            message.channel.send('You don\'t have the permission to do that!');
            console.log(consolewords('[CMD]: ') + consoleerrcmds(`${message.author.username} wanted to create a giveaway but didn't have the permission!`));
        }

    },
};
```

I'm getting this error code: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasPermission' of undefined`.
I'm not sure what is wrong because the same if-statement works on another commands!

Thank you in advance for helping!

Ps: I installed all packages. So there shouldn't be a problem!

Comment: `message.member` is ["only available if the message comes from a guild where the author is still a member"](https://discord.js.org#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=member).

Comment: Either the message is being sent in a dm, or you shuffled the parameter order.

Comment: Are you sure you passed the correct member object to the function?

Comment: So First of all thank you for all comments so far!
1.Yes i know. I am and was in the guild. That's not the problem

2. It was not send in a dm and the order should be correct!

3. Ye should be.

Comment: Oh nvm. One of the parameter was wrong! I wrote 10s instead of 10seconds!
The command is not working but I'm not getting errors anymore...

Comment: I would suggest ensuring that 'message' isn't undefined in the first place. The message variable may not be getting created properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here try using this (make sure to create a .env file for you token if you like):

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const { Client, Attachment, MessageEmbed } = ('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const ms = require("ms");
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 60;
const token = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN;

const PREFIX = '!';
 
 
const { GiveawaysManager } = require("discord-giveaways");
 
 
const manager = new GiveawaysManager(bot, {
    storage:  "./giveaways.json",
    updateCountdownEvery: 10000,
    default: {
        botsCanWin: false,
        embedColor: "#FF0000",
        reaction: ""
    }
})
 
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.tag} is ready to go.`)
})

bot.giveawaysManager = manager;
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    let msg = message.content.toLowerCase();
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return;
    }
 
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'gcreate':
            if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send('You do not have permission to use this command')
            let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
 
            if (!channel) return message.channel.send('Please provide a channel |  Usage: !gcreate {channel} {duration} {winners} {prize} ex: !gcreate #giveaways 1d 1 Awsome Prize');
 
            let giveawayDuration = args[2];
 
            if (!giveawayDuration || isNaN(ms(giveawayDuration))) return message.channel.send('Pleae provide a valid duration | Usage: !gcreate {channel} {duration} {winners} {prize} ex: !gcreate #giveaways 1d 1 Awsome Prize');
 
            let giveawayWinners = args[3];
 
            if (isNaN(giveawayWinners) || (parseInt(giveawayWinners) <= 0)) return message.channel.send('Please provide a valid number of winners! |  Usage: !gcreate {channel} {duration} {winners} {prize} ex: !gcreate #giveaways 1d 1 Awsome Prize');
 
            let giveawayPrize = args.slice(4).join(" ");
 
            if (!giveawayPrize) return message.channel.send('What prize do you wanna give? |  Usage: !gcreate {channel} {duration} {winners} {prize} ex: !gcreate #giveaways 1d 1 Awsome Prize');
            bot.giveawaysManager.start(channel, {
                time: ms(giveawayDuration),
                prize: giveawayPrize,
                winnerCount: giveawayWinners,
                hostedBy: message.author,
                messages: {
                    giveaway: "**GIVEAWAY**",
                    giveawayEnded: "**GIVEAWAY ENDED**",
                    timeRemaining: "Time remaining: **{duration}**",
                    inviteToParticipate: "React with  to enter",
                    winMessage: "Congrats {winners}, you won **{prize}**",
                    embedFooter: "Giveaway time!",
                    noWinner: "Couldn't determine a winner",
                    hostedBy: "Hosted by {user}",
                    winners: "winner(s)",
                    endedAt: "Ends at",
                    units: {
                        seconds: "seconds",
                        minutes: "minutes",
                        hours: "hours",
                        days: "days",
                        pluralS: false
                    }
                }
            });
            message.channel.send(`Giveaway starting in ${channel}`);
 
 
            break;
 
    }
});
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return;
    }
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'gedit':
            if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send('You do not have permission to use this command')
            let messageID = args[1];
            let giveawayDuration = args[2];
            if (!giveawayDuration || isNaN(ms(giveawayDuration))) return message.channel.send('Pleae provide a valid duration | ex: !gedit {messageid} 30s 3 nitro');
            let giveawayWinners = args[3];
            if (isNaN(giveawayWinners) || (parseInt(giveawayWinners) <= 0)) return message.channel.send('Please provide a valid number of winners! | ex: !gedit {messageid} 30s 3 nitro')
            let giveawayPrize = args.slice(4).join(" ");
            if (!messageID) message.channel.send('Please provide a message ID.')
            bot.giveawaysManager.edit(messageID, {
                newWinnerCount: giveawayWinners,
                newPrize: giveawayPrize,
                addTime: ms(giveawayDuration)
            }).then(() => {
                message.channel.send("Success! Giveaway will updated very soon.");
            }).catch((_err) => {
                message.channel.send("No giveaway found for " + messageID + ", please check and try again");
            });
            break;
    };
});
 
 
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return;
    }
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'gdelete':
            if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send('You do not have permission to use this command')
            let messageID = args[1];
            if (!messageID) return message.channel.send('No message ID provided')
            bot.giveawaysManager.delete(messageID).then(() => {
                message.channel.send("Success! Giveaway deleted!");
            }).catch((_err) => {
                message.channel.send("No giveaway found for " + messageID + ", please check and try again");
            });
 
            break;
    };
});
 
bot.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX)) return;
    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(' ');
    if (message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel.type === 'dm') {
        return;
    }
    switch (args[0]) {
        case 'greroll':
            if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return message.channel.send('You do not have permission to use this command')
            let messageID = args[1];
            if (!messageID) return message.channel.send('No message ID provided')
            bot.giveawaysManager.reroll(messageID).then(() => {
                message.channel.send("Success! Giveaway rerolled!");
            }).catch((_err) => {
                message.channel.send("No giveaway found for " + messageID + ", please check and try again");
            });
 
            break;
    };
});
bot.login(token)
```